# Effects of gamma irradiation on pH buffer

Tags: ph

Does anybody know if it is possible to gamma-irradiate a bottle of pH buffer to sterilise it? Are there any known effects (short-term or long-term) of the irradition process on the pH qualities of the buffer? This would be for a pH4 and pH7 buffer.

The other option I am considering is autoclaving, but I am told this will definitely affect the pH of the buffer solution, which I don't want.

Comment: I think it's virtually guaranteed that you'll reach sterilising doses of gamma radiation far before you create a bulk chemical change in the solutions, especially if the buffers are made with simple inorganic oxyhydrides (phosphate buffers?). Life is chemically far more fragile than a buffer solution. Also, the fact that gamma irradiation is a safe and proven method for sterilising food for human consumption is an additional argument in your favour. That said, gamma irradiation seems overkill. I'm not sure that autoclaving would **irreversibly** alter the pH, again depending on your buffer.

Comment: Wonder how an autoclave would work with a solution. If the pressure was created by steam, then the container shouldn't be at risk from the start of the cycle till 121 C is reached. However once the steam stops, the pressure inside the autoclave would start to drop. However the bottle of liquid would still be near 121 C, a high enough temperature to boil at atmospheric pressure.